# While performing squaring and square roots on floats: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Tags: c++, enums

I'm trying to square and square root a float, but I get the error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type
What does that mean? How can I fix that?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float X = 5.f;
    float Thing = X ^ 2;
    float Thing2 = sqrtf(X ^ 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `^` is not the power operator, it is the [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operator.

C++ doesn't have a power operator however since squaring is equivalent to multiplying by oneself it is almost always implemented that way.

```
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float X = 5.f;
    float Thing = X * X;
    float Thing2 = sqrtf(X * X); //Or Thing instead of X * X

    return 0;
}
```

There does exist a `pow` operator in `<math.h>` but it isn't the standard way of doing a square, since it has to have extra logic to allow the power to vary at run time.